# calculation of anomalies on time-series

Tags: r, time-series, plyr

I'd like to calculate monthly temperature anomalies on a time-series with several stations.
I call here "anomaly" the difference of a single value from a mean calculated on a period.

My data frame looks like this (let's call it "data"):

```
Station Year Month Temp
A 1950 1 15.6
A 1980 1 12.3
A 1990 2 11.4
A 1950 1 15.6
B 1970 1 12.3
B 1977 2 11.4
B 1977 4 18.6
B 1980 1 12.3
B 1990 11 7.4
```

First, I made a subset with the years comprised between 1980 and 1990:

```
data2 <- subset(data, Year>=1980& Year<=1990)
```

Second, I used plyr to calculate monthly mean (let's call this "MeanBase") between 1980 and 1990 for each station:

```
data3 <- ddply(data2, .(Station, Month), summarise,
               MeanBase = mean(Temp, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Now, I'd like to calculate, for each line of data, the difference between the corresponding MeanBase and the value of Temp... but I'm not sure to be in the right way (I don't see how to use data3).

Comment: it's Temp... I changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave` in base R to get this.

```
transform(data, 
          Demeaned=Temp - ave(replace(Temp, Year < 1980 | Year > 1990, NA), 
                              Station, Month, FUN=function(t) mean(t, na.rm=TRUE)))

#   Station Year Month Temp Demeaned
# 1       A 1950     1 15.6 3.3
# 2       A 1980     1 12.3 0.0
# 3       A 1990     2 11.4 0.0
# 4       A 1950     1 15.6 3.3
# 5       B 1970     1 12.3 0.0
# 6       B 1977     2 11.4 NaN
# 7       B 1977     4 18.6 NaN
# 8       B 1980     1 12.3 0.0
# 9       B 1990    11  7.4 0.0
```

The result column will have `NaN`s for Month-Station combinations that have no years in your specified range.

Comment: sorry I changed (again) my first post: the mean has to be calculated between 1980 and 1990 but the anomalies have to be calculated for all years of initial dataset

Comment: I don't think this calculates what I want. Maybe my explanation was unclear. What I would like to get is: i) for each station and for each month, a mean between 1980 and 1990 ii) for each station, each month, and all the years of the dataset, get the difference between the mean (calculated between 1980 and 1990) and the recorded value... this is what I call "anomaly"

Comment: That's what this does, but it then subtracts that mean from each temperature. Take out the 'Temp - ' to see the means.

Comment: Then, how is it possible to get NaN?

Comment: Because there are no years in your range for station B and Month 4.

Comment: OK, I see... it's because of the minimal example! Thank you @Matthew